# How can I get this math font?

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

I want to get this math font:

[image: This is the font I want to get]

But I can only get this one:

[image: This is the font I have]

I have tried different options but I can't get it. Can you tell me what options I need to change in order to make the separation between characters smaller and to change only the math font. I have checked different questions with my same issue, but I have not been able to reproduce their solutions.

Comment: Possibly not a good comment, but take it for what it is worth: LaTeX (maybe just LuaTeX) decides whether a font is a "math font" by looking to see if it has the `ssty` Open Type Feature. If you have FontForge, you can add `ssty` to any font. Of course, it must have the necessary characters, but many Open Type fonts do have them.

Comment: Could you tell us more about where and when this piece was published?

Comment: if you have the pdf of that document just look in the fonts menu (or use the pdffonts utiility) and get a list of fonts used, that is more accurate than asking people to guess which fonts are used in an image.

Comment: @RobtA is that at all useful unless you also add a Math table? wouldn't it be better to use the classic tex math font parameters even with an opentype font if it doesn't have a Math table?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are correct. It is also necessary to do more, not just add ssty. I made the assumption that the OP (being a math type) could take it from there. But the ssty part is enough to fool fontspec and unicode-math, as long as there is at least one table entry. Take any non-math font, add ssty with something such as mu substituting for u, and it will be permitted as a math font. May not be useful, though.

Comment: @RobtA sure but you could use the classic math setting using this font as long as you set some font parameters, so forcing the engine to think it's an opentype math font if it doesn't have a full math table seems harmful.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah. Then attention all readers: Disregard what I wrote about adding ssty. It is a potentially harmful trick. David Carlisle knows what he is talking about. As for me (I don't do math) I discovered that trick by accident.

Comment: @Mico This paper was published in the Journal of Computational Physics in 2012.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That would be great but my pdf reader doesn't show me any information about the fonts in the document. I actually asked this question because I'm not sure if it's definitely only changing the font type, or I can get that result by changing some options in the font type I already have. I'm very new with latex and I have not found how to play with the font type within different environments...I don't want to change the whole document font, but only the equations.

Comment: @Jaydi_21 the pdffonts utility comes with texlive (I am not sure if it comes with miktex) or you can use the freely available acrobat reader  or many other pdf viewers.

Comment: those bold letters look very bold, if it is mathtime heavy then that is a commercial font that you have to buy, but I don't have a sample to hand to compare.

Comment: Related: [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded a PDF from the Journal’s site and ran `pdffonts` on it, getting

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
MEGCHA+Gulliver                      Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    385  0
MEGCJA+Univers                       Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     386  0
MEGCJB+Helvetica                     Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     387  0
MEGCLB+Gulliver-Italic               Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    388  0
MEGCLC+GulliverSCOsF                 Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    389  0
MEGCLD+Symbol                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    403  0
MEGCLE+Gulliver-Bold                 Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    404  0
MEGCPD+MTMI                          Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    124  0
MEGCPE+MTSYN                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    128  0
MEGDBF+MTEX                          Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    129  0
```

This shows that the publisher is using proprietary fonts.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a times I had to use recently in a paper.
Try

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
```

Might be you have to install the according package if it is not available on your system.
This will probably also change the text font as shown in your figures.

Comment: I already have this in my preamble: 
    \usepackage{amssymb, amsbsy, amsfonts} 
    \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
I added 
    \usepackage{mathptmx}

But I don't see any change in the document. Besides I don't want to change the whole text, but only the math environments.